# Why didn't Lion Guard production keep the same designs for Kiara and Kovu?

Tags: the-lion-king, the-lion-guard

When Lion Guard first aired, I think I was not the only one who asked: "how will the existence of Kion retro-continue with the existence of Simba's Pride movie, where he didn't exist?", because Simba's Pride is of 1999 and Kion was not even a concept yet. The production managed to carry the plot well, however. The earlier scenes of Simba's Pride don't need to include Kion, and there was a good explanation of why Kion was not when Kovu appeared in public, and when the Outlanders vs. Pridelanders battle was running: Kion & co. were in a trip toward the Tree of Life.

In season 3 episode 19 (or 18 if you count Battle for the Pride Lands parts as a single episode), Janja and Jasiri manage to find the Tree of Life and tell Kion about Zira, and in episode 20 (or 19) they all manage to quickly come back to the Pride Lands taking a shortcut (mostly allowed due to new Kion's abilities using the Roar).

And they come across Vitani's Lion Guard. They start a short battle and then this happens: The battle is split by Kovu and Kiara's appearance in scene.

[image]

By looking them closely, paying attention mainly to the proportion of the heads, one can notice that both Kovu and Kiara are still young (teens, say, like Kion but a bit older as it should be). The weird part is that they looked more adult-like in my head. More Simba-like in size and proportions, in Simba's Pride (in fact, you can tell that when comparing the end scene of that movie where the four lions are roaring in the Pride Rock).

[image]

But the first time, one can tell better these details when Kovu and Kiara sing their song before the battle (one can better compare the heads proportions):

[image]

**My question** is: Is there an official response regarding the design change? The Lion Guard's scene is cronologically older than the Simba's Pride pre-battle song and the four lions roaring to the sky after the battle. Or it was just a mistake?